# Writing SQL in Rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model-view-controller

I have a payment_request model and a payment_detail model. In the payment_request index I need to be able to search by first and last name which are stored in the payment_details table. I am newish to writing SQL and could use some help. I have what I believe to be the correct query below, but am not sure how to write that in my Rails controller so I can search by name.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM payment_details
LEFT OUTER JOIN payment_requests
ON payment_requests.id = payment_details.payment_request_id;
```

Comment: can you post your existing code to saerch for payment_details via address or email address please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ActiveRecord models, you can skip all that and build that query with the [ActiveRecord Querying Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

```
@payment_requests = PaymentRequest.joins(:payment_detail).where(payment_detail: {first_name: params[:first_name], last_name: params[:last_name]})
```

If you intent to show `payment_details` data on that index page, you should consider including that information in that query, so you avoid `n+1` queries.

```
@payment_requests = PaymentRequest.includes(:payment_detail).where(payment_detail: { first_name: params[:first_name], last_name: params[:last_name]})
```

> Note: You've got to have a complete match to use the above, so it may not be what you want.

I'd also recommend you use the [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) gem to build complex queries. It would go something like this:

```
PaymentRequest.ransack(params[:q])
```

and in your views:

```
<%= f.search_field :payment_detail_first_name_or_payment_detail_last_name_cont %>
```

That would allow you to use just one field to query both columns.

Comment: This might seem like a silly question, but would I put the query in the payment_request or the payment_details controller? I am thinking the payment_request controller.

Comment: I'd keep it in payment_request, just like you did.

Comment: It isn't working for me. Gives me an error.

ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError in Matrix::PaymentRequests#index

Association named 'payment_detail' was not found on PaymentRequest; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: I'm assuming you have a relationship `belongs_to` and `has_one` between payment_request and payment_detail.

Comment: Then something happening there. Maybe you named the association differently. The Error is clearly stating Rails can't find the association `payment_detail` on `PaymentRequest`. You could start a console and check if you can fetch payment_detail data through payment_request, for instance. `PaymentRequest.first.payment_detail`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125115/discussion-between-mike-wiesenhart-and-alexandre-angelim).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
term_to_find = params[:search]
columns_to_search = %w( payment_details.first_name payment_details.last_name )
sql_conditions = []
columns_to_search.map |column_name|
  sql_conditions.push("#{column_name} ILIKE :term_to_find")
end
PaymentRequest.includes(:payment_details)
              .where(sql_conditions.join(' OR '), term_to_find: "%#{term_to_find}%")
```

This will find results containing the string you searched. Example: you typed "bob" in the search, it could find "bobby" or even "Mr. Bob" (the `ILIKE` makes the search case-insensitive)